# What does these mysql program options -N -B mean?

Tags: mysql

I've a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/sh
DB_HOST="localhost"
DB_PASS="pa**w0rd"
MYSQL="mysql --force --connect-timeout=90 --host=$DB_HOST -u root --password=${DB_PASS}"

USERS=`$MYSQL -N -B -e "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1;" first_db 2> /dev/null`

INSERT_USER=$($MYSQL -N -B -e "INSERT INTO users (\`username\`, \`password\`) VALUES('Adam', 'pa55word');" first_db 2> /dev/null)
```

I know **-e** means execute the command, but I don't know what **-N -B** does here. Can anybody please tell me?

Comment: Try `mysql --help`.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html) the official website that explains the usage of options of mysql. It says:

> -N option:
>
> Do not write column names in results.
>
> -B option:
>
> Print results using tab as the column separator, with each row on a new line. With this option, mysql does not use the history file. Batch mode results in nontabular output format and escaping of special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from mysql's man page:

> **--skip-column-names, -N**
>
> Do not write column names in results.

> **--batch, -B**
>
> Print results using tab as the column separator, with each row on a new line. With this option, mysql does not use the history file.
>
> Batch mode results in nontabular output format and escaping of special characters. Escaping may be disabled by using raw mode; see the description for the --raw option.